Azure AD B2C - Prevent email change in password reset journey using custom policy
We are using custom policies to allow users to reset their password. In the journey, when user is resetting the password, it provides a step to change the username/email, which we don't want to offer to end user.
Is there any way to prevent that step to be shown to user or remove from password reset user journey?
Below is the code for the same.
<UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
<OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedRegError" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-RegError" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
</OrchestrationSteps>
<ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>

This is how the change email screen looks to end user but we don't want user to see it. Is there any way to prevent showing this screen to user in the password reset journey?

